# Need help - Activate/Deactivate Filters via INPUT & BGColor

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

im looking for a solution to somehow turn a specific function of my strategy on and off so that I can easily see how the results change on the overview on tradingview.

Here's an example. I modified my strategy, so that I only open a new trade during a specific time.

```
tradinghours = time(timeframe.period, "0800-2200", "GMT+1")
bgcolor(not na(tradinghours) ? color.rgb(73, 196, 78, 75) : na)
time_condition = not na(tradinghours)

if (inDateRange and LongEntry and time_condition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, comment="entry long")
```

That's how I thought I could solve it:

```
FilterTradeTime = input.string(defval='On',title='Filter 0800-2200',options=['On','Off'])
FilterTradeTimeOn = if (FilterTradeTime=="On")
    1
else
    0

tradinghours = time(timeframe.period, "0800-2200", "GMT+1")
time_condition = not na(tradinghours)

if (FilterTradeTimeOn==1)
    time_condition := not na(tradinghours)
    bgcolor(not na(tradinghours) ? color.rgb(73, 196, 78, 75) : na)
else
    time_condition := na(tradinghours)

if (inDateRange and LongEntry and time_condition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, comment="entry long")
```

I always get the notification Cannot use 'bgcolor' in local scope

How can I change this? And is there an easier way to code this? Looking forward to some feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a [ternary](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D)

Something like that

```
i_period = input.bool (false, 'Period On/Off')

tradinghours = time(timeframe.period, "0800-2200", "GMT+1")
time_condition = i_period ? not na(tradinghours) : true

bgcolor(time_condition ? color.rgb(73, 196, 78, 75) : na)

if (inDateRange and LongEntry and time_condition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, comment="entry long")
```

Comment: Hey there - that didnt work. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Ok it actually does. Sorry I did some reasearch on inputt.bool and know I understand it. One more question. How should I set it up, so that the bgcolor is also only displayed, if the Period is On?

Comment: So if the Checkbox is not selected, the bgcolor for the whole chart is green. How can I change that to no bgcolor? Only if the checkbox is selected, the bgcolor should be activated.